# `inline` and `register` modules options

Tags: traceur

What do `--modules inline` and `--modules register` options do?

https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Using [2ality.com](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)'s `lib.js` example module:

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

//------ main.js ------
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

`inline` wraps the module in an anonymous function, assigned to an  auto-generated variable by the looks, it would be interesting to know what this is all about, the technique can be used to bundle modules without actually using a module system, but the `var` assigned the object returned would have to be known:

```
var $__src_47_lib_46_js__ = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = "src/lib.js";
  var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
  function square(x) {
    return x * x;
  }
  function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
  }
  return {
    get sqrt() {
      return sqrt;
    },
    get square() {
      return square;
    },
    get diag() {
      return diag;
    }
  };
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=lib.js.map
```

`System.register` is a draft [module format](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained):

```
System.registerModule("src/lib.js", [], function() {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = "src/lib.js";
  var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
  function square(x) {
    return x * x;
  }
  function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
  }
  return {
    get sqrt() {
      return sqrt;
    },
    get square() {
      return square;
    },
    get diag() {
      return diag;
    }
  };
});
System.get("src/lib.js" + '');
//# sourceMappingURL=lib.js.map
```

Once the module has been registered, then the `System.module( ... )` can be called to load the module.  Currently I know `traceur` (though not the runtime) has the System object polyfilled, presumably also `babel`.

The `System.register` format has some useful advantages I would suggest, more than one module can be included in a file which suits a collection of smaller closely coupled modules (typically classes); there is no need to buy in to another module system, e.g., including vanilla JS (test data, shims attached to the global object, etc.) in a node module requires additional boilerplate code adding overhead to the workflow, etc.

The `System` object though is technology still in development (not included the current draft standard).